# Using ReaderT to create a modifiable environment

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I have been following and expanding on the tutorial [Write Yourself A Scheme](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours). I have a type `LispVal` wrapped up in a couple of layers of monad transformers:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

data LispVal   = ...
data LispError = ...

type Bindings = M.Map String (IORef LispVal)
data Env = Environment { parent :: Env, bindings :: IORef Bindings }

type IOThrowsError = ErrorT LispError IO
type EvalM = ReaderT Env IOThrowsError
```

The idea with using `ReaderT` is that I'll be able to automatically pass the environment (which maintains variable bindings) around through the evaluator, and it will be obvious where it is used because there will be a call to `ask`. This seems preferable to explicitly passing the environment around as an extra parameter. When I come to implement continuations I'll want to do a similar trick with the `ContT` monad transformer, and avoid passing around an extra argument for the continuation.

However, I haven't figured out how it's possible to *modify* the environment by doing this. For example, to define a new variable or to set the value of an old one.

For a concrete example, let's say that whenever I evaluate an if statement, I want to bind the variable `it` to the result of the test clause. My first thought was to modify the environment directly:

```
evalIf :: [LispVal] -> EvalM LispVal
evalIf [test, consequent, alternate] = do
  result <- eval test
  bind "it" result
  case (truthVal result) of
    True  -> eval consequent
    False -> eval alternate
```

Here `truthVal` is a function that assigns a `Bool` to any `LispVal`. But I can't figure out how to write the function `bind` so that it modifies the environment.

My second thought was to use `local`:

```
evalIf :: [LispVal] -> EvalM LispVal
evalIf [test, consequent, alternate] = do
  result <- eval test
  local (bind "it" result) $ case (truthVal result) of
    True  -> eval consequent
    False -> eval alternate
```

But here `bind` needs to have type `Env -> Env`, and since I'm using `IORef`s as values in the environment, I can only write a function with the signature `Env -> IO Env`.

Is this even possible, or do I need to use `StateT` instead of `ReaderT`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ReaderT` is used when you have scoped, read-only environments. E.g. in interpreters.
Environments in `ReaderT` nest lexically, so you can augment the environment each time you encounter a binding. Like so:

```
eval (LetE x e1 e2) = do
    env <- ask
    v   <- eval e1
    local (M.insert x v) (eval e2)
```

Here's [an old post](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2006/12/11/quick-interpreters-with-the-reader-monad/) of mine with some examples.

If you have such an environment, it shouldn't be necessary to also use `IORefs`, unless you're playing funny games with dynamic scoping? What is the reason for the IORefs?

Comment: `eval` for the `LetE` case appears to `ask` for the environment unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a modifiable context, `StateT` is what you need rather than `ReaderT`. Reader will only allow you to `ask`, not `tell` (as in `WriterT`). State is a composition of Reader and Writer, allowing you to `get`, `put`, and `modify` at will.

Comment: Technically, the `Writer`'s `tell` function appends its `Monoid` argument to the `Monad`'s state, where as the `State`'s `put` function replaces the `Monad`'s state.